# Best algorithm for equal division number between column with ratio

Tags: algorithm, math

I have some number like this table:

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| e      | d           | c           | b          | a          |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 170000 | -228253.968 | -415460.317 | 124047.618 | 349666.667 |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

I want best algorithm to find how much should the negative columns add to the positive columns so that all columns become zero?

for example:

```
c (349666.667) to a (now c = -65793.65 & a = 0 )
d (170000) to e (now d = -58253.968 & e = 0)
c (65793.65) to b ( now c = 0 & b = 58253.968)
e (58253.968) to b ( now e = 0 & b = 0)
```

Comment: Is the forward slash, `/` supposed to be decimal point delimiter?

Comment: In any case, I keep looking at your question and it's leaving out some important details. Could you try to improve your question?  Look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or use the [rubber duck method](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/) for hints on how to ask your question.

Comment: @selbie Sorry, yes. I edit table with decimal point.

Comment: That's not the only issue with your question.  The rest doesn't make much sense and could use a lot of improvement on what algorithm you are trying to apply to the spreadsheet.

Comment: I simplified my question

Comment: I don't really get your problem. Is the order or amount you add to `c` or `d` in the various steps, or the number of steps of any importance? Does it make any difference if you start with `(c -> 170000) -> a` such that  `(now c = -245640.317 and e = 0)` and then continue to drain `c` towards `a`, ie `(c ->245640.317) -> a` such that `c = 0 and a = 104026.35)` and then `(d -> 104026,35)` such that `(d = -332280,318 and a = 0)` and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to ask, however from what I can understand it seems as if you want to know the best way to get all of the columns to equal zero after adding and subtracting them from each other.

The most efficient way that I can think of to accomplish this would be as follows.

For every row add the complete value of that row to the next row.

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| e      | d           | c           | b          | a          |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 170000 | -228253.968 | -415460.317 | 124047.618 | 349666.667 |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+


d = d + e
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| e      | d           | c           | b          | a          |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 0      | -58253.968  | -415460.317 | 124047.618 | 349666.667 |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+

c = c + d
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| e      | d           | c           | b          | a          |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 0      | 0           | -473714.285 | 124047.618 | 349666.667 |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+

b = b + c
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| e      | d           | c           | b           | a          |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| 0      | 0           | 0           | -349666.667 | 349666.667 |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+

a = a + b
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| e      | d           | c           | b           | a          |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| 0      | 0           | 0           | 0           | 0          |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

This method assumes that the sum of all of the rows is equal to zero just as the table you provided. Again, the question was not very well formatted so this is just a guess as to what I think you wanted to be solved.